# Common Python scripts are getting called multiple times

Tags: python

I have the following project structure.

```
 - README.rst
 - LICENSE
 - setup.py
 - requirements.txt
 - common_prj/__init__.py
 - common_prj/common_lib.py
 - common_prj/config.xml
 - Project1/__init__.py
 - Project1/some_app_m1.py
 - Project1/some_app_m2.py
 - Project1/some_app.py
 - Project2/some_app1.py
```

I am having all my common classes in common_prj/common_lib.py file. Now each module file from Project1 is calling common_prj/common_lib.py to access common classes and setup project env using config.xml

#import in some_app_m1.py

---

```
from common_prj import common_lib
```

#import in some_app_m2.py

---

```
from common_prj import common_lib
```

### Imports in some_app.py

---

```
from Project1 import some_app_m1
from Project1 import some_app_m2 
from common_prj import common_lib
###
  <some functions>
  <some functions>
###
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

With the above three import it seems common_lib.py is getting executed multiple time , but if I keep the common_lib.py in Project1 then I don't see this issue.

Please let me now how can I keep common_lib.py in common package and call that from Project1 scripts without executing it multiple time. The purpose of common_lib.py is to share common classes with scripts in Project2.

I have the below code in common_lib.py which is repeating for calling classes from each module after import.

---

```
self.env = dict_env.get(int(input("Choose Database ENV for this execution : \n" + str(dict_env) + "\nSelect the numeric value => ")))
self.app = dict_app.get(int(input("Choose application for this execution : \n" + str(dict_app) + "\nSelect the numeric value => ")))
```

---

**My question why I am not facing this issue if I keep common_lib.py in Project1 rather common_prj. I added the above code in common_lib.py because I don't wanted to repeat these lines and ENV setup in my all app code. These are global env settings for all application scripts code inside Project1.**

---

**output**

---

```
Choose Database ENV for this execution : 
{1: 'DEV', 2: 'SIT', 3: 'UAT', 4: 'PROD'}
Select the numeric value => 1
Choose application for this execution : 
{1: 'app1', 2: 'app2', 3: 'app3', 4: 'app4', 5: 'app5', 6: 'app6'}
Select the numeric value => 1
Choose Database ENV for this execution : ### Here it is repeating again from common_lib.py
{1: 'DEV', 2: 'SIT', 3: 'UAT', 4: 'PROD'}
Select the numeric value => 1
Choose application for this execution : ### Here it is repeating again from common_lib.py
{1: 'app1', 2: 'app2', 3: 'app3', 4: 'app4', 5: 'app5', 6: 'app6'}
Select the numeric value => 1
```

Comment: use `if __name__ == '__main__':` maybe that helps the issue and put all function calls (in modules You import from) under it, also You can do `from package import some_app_m1, some_app_m2, common_lib`

Comment: I have  added that in my code , but no luck.

Comment: what exactly did You add? because `if __name__ == '__main__':` will certainly not allow functions to execute (if You put those functions under the statement), here is more about it: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-the-if-__name__-__main__-do/)

Comment: I have the main function and called import from the function where I need to import some_app_m1 , but when the scripts approaches hat function it again executing comon_lib and as I mentioned I am setting env in connon_lib , hence my env is getting rest again each import of modules

Comment: so You are saying that importing a module causes it to run?.... use `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: Yes , I have an Input statements in my common_lib.py to set env , that is repeating each time common_lib.py is called by each import module ,sine each module is alos importing common_lib.py. I added the output for better understanding

Comment: Don't let anything in common_lib execute on anything. Wrap everything in functions and classes. The caller should be the one in charge of executing.

Comment: I have the below code to set env for the scrits as one time for each execution 
 self.env = dict_env.get(int(input("Choose Database ENV for this execution : \n" + str(dict_env) + "\nSelect the numeric value => ")))
        self.app = dict_app.get(int(input("Choose application for this execution : \n" + str(dict_app) + "\nSelect the numeric value => ")))

Comment: In a library module you shouldn't be doing anything on import, only define functions, classes, constants etc. If the library needs parameters, the caller should supply those, ideally in a way that allows multiple different sets of parameters to be used.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This is my first answer where I answer in-depth of the logistics of python. If I have said anything incorrect, please let me know or edit my answer (with a comment letting me know why). Please feel free to clarify any questions you may have too.

---

As the comments have discussed `if __name__ == '__main__':` is exactly the way to go. You can check out the [answers on the SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for a full description or check out the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).

In essence, `__name__` is a variable for a python file. Its behavior includes:

- When used in a file, its value is defaulted to `'__main__'`.
- When a file imports another program. (`import foo`). `foo.__name__` will return `'foo'` as its value.

Now, when importing a file, python compiles the new file completely. This means that it will run everything that can be run. Python compiles all the methods, variables, etc. As it's compiling, if python comes across a callable function (i.e `hello_world()`) it will run it. This happens even if you're trying to import a specific part of the package or not.

Now, these two things are very important. If you have some trouble understanding the logic, you can take a look at some [sample code](https://replit.com/@12944qwerty/testing-1#main.py) I created.

Since you are importing from `common_prj` 3 times (from the `some_app_m*` file and `my_app.py` file), you are running the program in `common_prj` three times (This is also what makes python one of the slower programming languages).

Although I'm unable to see your complete code, I'm assuming that `common_prj.py` calls `common_lib()` at some point in your code (at no indentation level). This means that the two methods inside:

```py
self.env = dict_env.get(int(input("Choose Database ENV for this execution : \n" + str(dict_env) + "\nSelect the numeric value => ")))
self.app = dict_app.get(int(input("Choose application for this execution : \n" + str(dict_app) + "\nSelect the numeric value => ")))
```

were also called.

**So, in conclusion:**

1. You imported `common_prj` 3 times
2. Which ran `common_lib` multiple times as well.

**Solution:**

- This is where the `__name__` part I talked about earlier comes into play
- Take all callable functions that shouldn't be called during importing, and place them under the conditional of `if __name__ == '__name__':`
- This will ensure that only if the `common_prj` file is run then the condition will pass.

Again, if you didn't understand what I said, please feel free to ask or look at my [sample code](https://replit.com/@12944qwerty/testing-1#main.py)!

**Edit:** You can also just remove these callable functions. Files that are meant to be imported use them to make sure that the functions work as intended. If you look at any of the packages that you import daily, you'll either find that the methods are called in the condition *OR* not in the file at all.

Comment: Note that importing a module three times may run it once, twice or three times; Python caches imports in `sys.modules`, so in many cases it'll run the module just once.

Comment: @sabik I'm still not quite familiar with how python fully works. But thank you! OP must have accidentally called it somewhere else....

Comment: Either that, or imported it in some way that imports the module under several different fully-qualified names or in some other way missed the cache...

Comment: My question why I am not facing this issue if I keep common_lib.py in Project1 rather common_prj.I added thebelow code in common_lib.py because I don't wanted to repeat these line in my all app code. These are global env setting for all application scripts code inside Project1.
self.env = dict_env.get(int(input("Choose Database ENV for this execution : \n" + str(dict_env) + "\nSelect the numeric value => ")))
self.app = dict_app.get(int(input("Choose application for this execution : \n" + str(dict_app) + "\nSelect the numeric value => ")))

Comment: @ArindamPal It's hard to tell from the code. Is it possible to clone it on github or something? I can try messing around and see exactly what's going wrong....

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question of library design, rather than the detailed mechanics of Python.

A library module (which is what `common_prj` is) should be designed to do nothing on import, only define functions, classes, constants etc. It can do things like pre-calculating constants, but it should be restricted to things that don't depend on anything external, produce the same results each time and don't involve much heavy computation. At that point, the code running three times will no longer be a problem.

If the library needs parameters, the caller should supply those, ideally in a way that allows multiple different sets of parameters to be used within the same program. Depending on the situation, the parameters can be a main object that manages the rest of the interaction, or parameters that are passed into each object constructor or function call, or a configuration object that's passed in. The library can provide a function to gather these parameters from the environment or user input, but it shouldn't be required; it should always be possible for the program to supply the parameters directly. This will also make tests easier to write.

Side notes:

- The name "common" is a bit generic; consider renaming the library after what it does, or splitting it into several libraries each of which does one thing?
- Python will try to cache imported modules so it doesn't re-run them multiple times; this is probably why it only ran the code once in one situation but three times in another. This is another reason to have only definitions happen on import, so the details of the caching don't affect functionality.

Comment: I added those two lines in common_lib.py because to setup ENV at top level and don't wanted to repeat the common ENV setup for each scripts in Project1 or Project2.  Also this issue I am not facing if I keep common_lib.py at Project1 or Project2 level.

Comment: Put those two lines in a function then call that function from each of the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems after commenting the below in

> Project1/**init**.py

the issue has been resolved. I was calling the same common_lib from **init**.py as well which was causing this issue . Removing the below entry resolved the issue.

```
#from common_prj import commonlib
```

---